# Custom exception default logging

Tags: python, exception, logging

I've built custom exceptions that accept a parameter(s) and format their own message from constants. They also print to stdout so the user understands the issue.

For instance:

```
defs.py:
PATH_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 'Cannot find path "{}"'

exceptions.py:
class PathNotFound(BaseCustomException):
    """Specified path was not found."""

    def __init__(self, path):
        msg = PATH_NOT_FOUND_ERROR.format(path)
        print(msg)
        super(PathNotFound, self).__init__(msg)

some_module.py
raise PathNotFound(some_invalid_path)
```

I also want to log the exceptions as they are thrown, the simplest way would be:

```
logger.debug('path {} not found'.format(some_invalid_path)
raise PathNotFound(some_invalid_path)
```

But doing this all across the code seems redundant, and especially it makes the constants pointless because if I decide the change the wording I need to change the logger wording too.

I've trying to do something like moving the logger to the exception class but makes me lose the relevant `LogRecord` properties like `name`, `module`, `filename`, `lineno`, etc. This approach also loses `exc_info`

Is there a way to log the exception and keeping the metadata without logging before raising every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone's interested, here's a working solution

The idea was to find the raiser's frame and extract the relevant information from there.
Also had to override `logging.makeRecord` to let me override internal LogRecord attributes

### Set up logging

```
class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    """Custom Logger."""

    def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
        """Override default logger to allow overridding internal attributes."""
        if six.PY2:
            rv = logging.LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
        else:
            rv = logging.LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, sinfo)

        if extra is not None:
            for key in extra:
                # if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
                #     raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
                rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
        return rv



logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

### Custom Exception Handler

```
class BaseCustomException(Exception):
    """Specified path was not found."""

    def __init__(self, path):
    """Override message with defined const."""
    try:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Find the traceback frame that raised this exception
        exception_frame = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back.f_back

    exception_stack = traceback.extract_stack(exception_frame, limit=1)[0]
    filename, lineno, funcName, tb_msg = exception_stack

    extra = {'filename': os.path.basename(filename), 'lineno': lineno, 'funcName': funcName}
    logger.debug(msg, extra=extra)
    traceback.print_stack(exception_frame)
    super(BaseCustomException, self).__init__(msg)
```